# HTTP Request Source to a Kafka Sink?

Tags: apache-kafka, playframework, akka-stream

How do I connect a play POST route to a Kafka Sink?

I found https://github.com/jamesward/hello-play-kafka.
But it uses a tick source of random numbers to attach to the Kafka sink.[1](https://github.com/jamesward/hello-play-kafka/blob/d9d0268521064a94d8a4e11cd7c5975381e1e10f/app/workers/RandomNumbers.scala)

How do I make a POST request route be a source to tie into a Kafka sink?

Edit: The format of the POST request body is json with a Content-Type of application/json. The message sent to kafka should be the exact same json. The route expects a single json message.

Comment: Please add more details to the question: What is the format of the POST request data? Can you describe how that should translate to the messages published to Kafka? Is there a stream of messages in each request, or do you want to send the complete POST body to Kafka in one message?

Comment: @TimMoore I added the edits you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question, but you can use the REST Proxy to send messages to Kafka:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.json.v2+json" \
      --data '{ "records": [ { "value": { "name": "testUser0" } }, { "value": { "name": "testUser1" } } ] }' \
      "http://localhost:8082/topics/jsontest"
```

Ref: [Confluent REST Proxy docs](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/api.html#post--topics-(string-topic_name)?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=rmoff&utm_campaign=ty.community.con.rmoff_stackoverflow_2020-06-17&utm_term=rmoff-devx)

Comment: I have considered this. I did no go with this as I may want to add features such as authZ and authN and other sinks to this flow in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Since your POST requests are going directly into Kafka, one-to-one, it isn't clear that a streaming model as provided by Akka Streams is a good fit. It might be more straightforward to use the [`KafkaProducer`](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html) API directly, to send messages one at a time to a Kafka topic. This would make the code, and particularly error handling, much simpler.

There may still be a good reason to prefer to use Akka Streams, for example to manage concurrency or ordering. The specific reasons could influence the best approach to take with it, so if you have more details on that, please add to the question and I'll update the answer.

For example, if you want to ensure that there are no concurrent writes, you might register a class as a singleton in Guice (assuming that you're using Guice for dependency injection). When it's created, it runs an Akka Stream using [`Source.queue`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/queue.html), [`Source.actorRef`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/actorRef.html), or [`Source.actorRefWithBackpressure`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source/actorRefWithBackpressure.html) along with a Kafka `Sink`. It would also need to use [`RestartSource`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/RestartSource/onFailuresWithBackoff.html) to ensure the stream restarts if there's an error. Expose a public method that allows callers to send messages to the materialized source queue or actor, and then inject the singleton into your controller class to allow it to publish its POST data using that method.

A big drawback to this approach is that the controller action would only be able to know that a message was successfully sent to the stream, and not that it was successfully written all the way to Kafka. If the Kafka brokers are down, the application crashes, or the write fails for some other reason, the message could be lost, even after returning a successful result to the initiating client. This isn't a problem for all use cases, but needs to be considered.